# jQuery Mobile - Loading Message

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile for the first time to make it so that I can swipe back to the previous page, which I have managed to get working.

However I have noticed a big ugly "loading" message at the bottom of the screen. After googling I have seen a function called `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` which I added inside my `$(document).ready(function()` but the loading message is still there.

How can I get rid of this message?

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

I solved the issue by using a jquery selector and hiding the element, like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".ui-loader").hide();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The proper usage of `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` is to show the Loading Message manually by triggering `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`.

Source: [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html)

In your case, if you want to disable this feature, insert the below code in `<head>` tag **BEFORE** loading JQM `<script src="Jquery.mobile.1.2.0.js">`

The code:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- disable loading msg -->
 <script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
 $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
});
 </script>
<!-- / -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Cheers, its working. I still have a white space where the message was though, any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: The loading div is still there. It needs to be removed, however, it shouldn't be shown. Can you post your code and a photo if possible?

Comment: I fixed it with this in the end:  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){ $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); });. Now to work out why hide / show no longer work!

Comment: Scrap that, that broke it hence why the message went away, grr!

Comment: You got it fixed or what?

Answer (score 1):

## loading

If the above is the issue you are talking about make sure you have the stylesheet loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
```