# Removing "Loading Message"

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, loading, message

I face a problem when i try to use jqm in my website. A message of 'loading' appears on the bottom of my site. I figured out that it happens since I don't add jqm css. When I add the jqm css  everything changes (color layout ect.). How is it possible to remove 'loading' message or  add css without conflicts with the main css of my site?

```
<head>
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
<!--<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- disable loading msg -->    
 <script>
   $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
   });
 </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">     </script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I add script in my code. Nothing seems to happen! My problem solved only when i uncomment jqm css code, but then i got many conflicts with the site.css which i dont know how to solve.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15276241/1771795 of how to disable ajax loading message

Comment: then you need to remove the div containing the loading message `$(".ui-loader").remove();`.

Comment: I ve alredy tried it. Nothing!! Same result with .hide().

Comment: `.remove()` should remove it. anyway try add css structure http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css

Comment: With the downloaded jqm css i got problems but with yours css it works fine!! Weird!!

Comment: this is a structure used for custom CSS created by themeroller. http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css

Comment: btw, the way you used `mobileinit` is wrong. it should be loaded after jQuery and before jQuery Mobile in head. double check the answer I've given you in the first comment.

Comment: You re right, thanks Omar!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile - Loading Message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275933/jquery-mobile-loading-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable jQuery Mobile loading message, you need to override global settings once `mobileinit` triggers. The code should be placed in `head` after loading jQuery and before loading jQuery Mobile libraries.

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
    });
  </script>
  <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
</head>
```